# Automatically generate random polygons with a given number of vertices

Tags: postgis-2.0

Updated to make it clear.

What would be the fastest way to generate a random polygon in PostGIS with a specific number of vertices? I want to create a PostGIS function like

```
GeneratePolygon(1000, 4326)
```

That would generate a polygon of 1000 vertices using SRS 4326.

I'm not worried about the type of polygon, just about the number of vertices, for db performance. For example: will it be able to store and retrieve polygons with 100K vertices? How fast?

A possible way to generate polygons would be to *sew* 1000 points of a GPX track, forming a linestring, and make that the exterior bound of a polygon. I guess the function [ST_MakePolygon](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePolygon.html) could be used for something like that. The trick, I think, is how to generate the points. Something like the *True* part of this image

[image: Union of points forming a polygon]

Comment: Please edit the question to include both a definition of "easier" and the desired characteristics of the created polygons (e.g., regular/irregular, concave/convex,...).  As written there are an infinite number of possible solutions (few of them efficient).

Comment: Perhaps studyinf JTS test builder could give some ideas. JTS does not build random polygons, though, but maybe other random geometries can be used as helpers, like in http://lists.refractions.net/pipermail/jts-devel/2009-June/003040.html,

Comment: Do you have a size requirement?  Like, could the polygon be 1m² in area?  Or 1000ha?  Also, your example of using a GPX track wouldn't be random.  It already exists.

Comment: Not really. Just want to test how the db works with different amount of vertices. For example: will it be able to handle polygons with 100K vertices? So, not really worried about the area, or the shape

Comment: ConvexHull? > Polygon https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471079/geting-convexhull-using-longitude-and-longitude-postgis